# Stop wildcard SSL redirecting subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I got a website `example.com` using a wildcard SSL. And so whenever I try to get on the subdomain `abc.example.com` it keeps on redirecting it back to `example.com`. How can I stop the redirect? I saw that adding a condition in the `.htaccess` file can solve the problem, but then all answers I found have different conditions and I'm afraid if I change the wrong one it will mess up the whole site.

This is from the subdomain's `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http://abc.example.com%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:https://abc.example.com%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
```

So what condition should I add in order to stop the redirect? Both websites are using WordPress if it helps, and I found this code under `# BEGIN W3TC CDN`.

Comment: ServerFault.com is a better place to ask questions about professional webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule *looks* fine, if silly (just enforce SSL), so I'm left with wondering if this is the exact code that is actually redirecting the browser.  I suspect it's Wordpress that is doing the redirecting; did you copy the database and forget to update the appropriate rows in new DB?  I generally use this script when I need to move (in your case, copy) a Wordpress site:

```
SET @oldsite='http://example.com';
SET @newsite='https://abc.example.com';
UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, @oldsite, @newsite);
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, @oldsite, @newsite) WHERE option_name IN ('home', 'siteurl');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, @oldsite, @newsite);
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, @oldsite, @newsite);
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, @oldsite, @newsite);
```

Change the first two lines/variables as appropriate, and run that against the database of the problem site.

Secondly, unless you want to hard redirect folks to `abc`, don't hardcode the host; use the `Host` header the client/browser sent as part of the initial request:

```
    RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
```

Meanwhile, consider just enforcing SSL in today's day and age:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```